# Highcharts : display a second series under the X-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to draw hourly statuses as (clickable) colored boxes under the X-axis of a chart with time series.

One idea is to have a second series (with its own Y-axis) drawn between the X-axis itself and the X-Axis labels.

But is it even possible to have 2 y-Axis going in opposite direction from a common X-Axis ?

```
   ^
   |
___|_____________>
           |
           | 
           V
```

Here is what I got so far :
http://jsfiddle.net/7q15t2fh/4/

Comment: There are a lot of potential solutions. 1) just use the same y axis, and use negative values; 2) Just make this its own chart aligned below the original so you don't have to worry about sizing the boxes in relation to the regular data 3) yes, you can have stacked y axes - look at the "top" and "offset" properties.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g4bwgj8n/ or http://jsfiddle.net/kzqdovrx/ ?

Comment: My take on it:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7q15t2fh/7/

Comment: My hackish take on the 1 axis solution : http://jsfiddle.net/7q15t2fh/8/

Comment: The main problem is that the first series values range can vary considerably from thousands to millions units. Thus is it not really practical to size the "status" line.

@jlbriggs : I failed to locate the "top" property you mention. Also, I'll try the 2) solution if everything else fails (because of potential alignments problems).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be a problem. See answer below for solution with 2 stacked axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that used two stacked y axes:

```
    yAxis: [{   
      height:200,
      title: { text: 'Y Axis 0', rotation:0 },
      offset:0
    },{
      top:275,
      height:30,
      title: { text: 'Y Axis 1', rotation:0 },
      offset:0,
      min:0,
      max:1
    }]
```

It looks like the "top" property is not listed in the API.

You need to set the height of each y axis, and the top of the second y axis, according to the size of your chart, and the top and bottom margins, and the spacing and block size that you want.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/u4db8yx7/

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for the example. Yep, top is undocumented.
Your solution looks very clean, but the hardcoded sizing might be a problem...

Comment: What would change that would make the hard coded sizing a problem? If you know how tall you want your clickable boxes, you should be able to determine the rest dynamically anyway

Comment: You're right, recalculating the axis heights and positions on a resize event would solve this issue. Another mostly working solution involve using % for the height and top attributes.

Comment: I validate your solution because it does reply exactly to the question I asked and solves the initial problem. Thanks for your time !